# Problems with keyboard mapping - lowercase 'v' is not working

Tags: linux, ubuntu, keyboard, ubuntu-10.04, gnome

I have quite a strange issue with (supposedly) my keyboard mappings.

- while using GNOME session:

  - lowercase 'v' is not working as it should - no keypress is reaching apps;
  - while I'm holding V key depressed, gnome-terminal console shows a hollow cursor (just like when input focus is in some other window) and nothing is printed;
  - uppercase 'V' is working just fine (that is Shift+V);
  - if I press AltGr + V, a lowercase 'v' is printed;
  - if I'm typing quickly, sometimes pressing V key to get a lowercase 'v' is not just being ignored, but also the next symbol typed is swallowed and not printed out;
  - this issue is present for the USA keyboard layout, as well as for the Russian keyboard layout.
- while using TTY console (Alt+Ctrl+F1, etc):

  - everything works as it should (i.e. lowercase ' is printed whenever I press it);
  - no problems with the physical keyboard.

I haven't done any editing of any gnome/X configs  and/or keyboard mappings.

What should I check?

PS. I'm a newbie to Linux (just 1.5 years) - please be explicit in your recommendations. :)
PPS. This is my Ubuntu 10.04 Linux version:

```
$ uname -a
Linux hostname 2.6.32-25-generic #44-Ubuntu SMP Fri Sep 17 20:05:27 UTC 2010 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Update - stty output:

```
$ stty -a
speed 38400 baud; rows 43; columns 151; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = M-^?; eol2 = M-^?; swtch = M-^?; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W;
lnext = ^V; flush = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd cs8 hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff -iuclc ixany imaxbel iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt echoctl echoke
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Chris Billington on askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8478/what-is-causing-my-spacebar-to-randomly-stop-working) I've found the cause of the problem - it was a Compiz key mapping for V key (initiate viewport switching).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the **lnext** parameter in the terminal driver got mangled somehow. You can use `stty` to change it.

Comment: I've added stty output to the question above. Looks fine for me. Are there any visible issues?